# Compiler error using java generics with a List as a method parameter and throws generic Exception

Tags: java, generics, interface

I'm getting a Compiler error when using generics in my project. I generate a sample code:

My Bean  Interface

```
package sample;

public interface MyBeanInterface {
  Long getId();
  String getName();
}
```

My Bean Concrete Class

```
package sample;

public class MyBean implements MyBeanInterface {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My Manager Interface

```
package sample;

import java.util.List;

public interface MyManagerInterface<T extends MyBeanInterface> {

    <EXCEPTION extends Exception> List<T> sortAll(List<T> array) throws EXCEPTION;

    List<T> sortAll2(List<T> array);

    <EXCEPTION extends Exception> List<T> sortAll3() throws EXCEPTION;

}
```

My Manager Concrete Class

```
package sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MyConcreteManager implements MyManagerInterface<MyBean> {

   @Override
   //this fails
   public List<MyBean> sortAll(List<MyBean> array) throws IOException {
       return null;
      }

    @Override
   //this works
    public List<MyBean> sortAll2(List<MyBean> array) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
   //this works
    public List<MyBean> sortAll3() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I tried using the method sortAll with no method parameters (sortAll()) in the interface and it compiles, using only the exception in the interface also works, but using both not.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you include the compilation error message you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to the `sortAll(List<T> list)` method, you have to do:

```
@Override
public <E extends Exception> List<T> sortAll(List<T> array) throws E {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

and then, when invoking the method to explicitly set the methods type-parameter:

```
try {
    new MyConcreteManager().<IOException>sortAll(...);
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

The `sortAll3()` implementation compiles fine, because in Java, when a method definition overrides another one, it is not allowed to throw additional checked exceptions, but it may throw fewer.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know you could even do this with `throws` type-parameters, where they're parameterized at the method level instead of the class level. Is there a reason to do so, instead of just saying `throws Exception` and letting subclasses narrow the signature in the old pre-generics manner? How do you get it to work if one of the method implementations might actually throw an exception? I put a `throw new IOException();` in to the `sortAll` body and it gave me a compiler error about undeclared exceptions. (Sorry; I couldn't easily find doco on this variant of generics.)

Comment: when you do `throw new IOException()` then your method must have a `throws` clause. However, if you've decided to narrow the list of possibly thrown checked exceptions, then there's no reason do have such `throw new IOException()` statements, right? :)

Comment: I'm still confused. With the interface as defined here, including the signature: `<EXCEPTION extends Exception> List<T> sortAll(List<T> array) throws EXCEPTION;` – what does that `throws` clause actually mean? What exceptions are implementing classes allowed to throw from that method? If I change the `throws` in the overridden method to be `throws IOException` instead of `<E extends Exception> ... throws E`, then the compiler complains that I haven't overridden the abstract inherited method.

Comment: I guess I'm asking, what does one do in a subclass to allow it to actually throw an `IOException` from its overridden `sortAll` method?

Comment: To be more specific: here's how I was thinking one might want to use the interface. What would one do to make this compile? Or am I misunderstanding what the parameterized `throws` list means? https://gist.githubusercontent.com/apjanke/a185d27b4217d893d3e7/raw/b473a7ca1c036e151d15d15b82c31e2feb4864e0/GenExInterface.java